# Are edits for just filling in image descriptions accepted?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits, peer-review

I'm a somewhat new user on this site and I was wondering, I've come across many posts that have an image within them but with no image description or it still includes the default message of, "enter image description here". I do not yet have enough reputation where my edits are instant and have to go under peer review. If I were to edit these posts only filling in a description of the image and change nothing else, would that be substantially enough to get accepted under the peer review?

Comment: Personally, I would reject an edit, if the only thing it did was provide an image description.  You can be banned from suggesting edits if enough edits are rejected.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. *if* they are alongside other *reasonably substancial* edits, go ahead. Editing to fix something 90% of our users will never see seems pointless.

One exception might be if the question would be of interest to someone who uses a screen reader, in which case, go ahead. Just make sure you mention that in the edit summary.

I'd also keep in mind that *seeking* these out, and the resulting flood page edits might make people irate, new user or not.